# My folder sometimes opens in a new window and even twice

Tags: windows-8.1, folder-redirection

Even though I have set to open all folders in the same window, sometimes folders open in a new window and twice. It always happens with the download folder. I can't figure out why. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

It might occur due to the folder in its own window ,to modify it :

Navigate to organize -->folder options

At general tab under browse folders -->select open each folder in the same window

click on apply ond ok

[image]